# Nested keyword arguments emitting TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, keyword-argument

I have a shim that is calling `requests.Session.send` under the hood.

Essentially it's:

```
def send(self, request: requests.PrepareRequest, **kwargs):
    ...
    super().send(request=request, **kwargs)
    ...
```

When calling this function with `session.send(request=Request("GET", "http://www.example.com").prepare(), myflag=False)` I get the following type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/path/to/shim-requests.py", line X, in send
    response = super().send(request=request, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/virtualenvs/my-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line Y, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'myflag'
```

Deleting `myflag` from the `kwargs` before calling `super().send()` prevents the `TypeError` but would like to understand what is going on.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems that `super().send(request=request, **kwargs)` (the parent class' method `.send()`) doesn't accept the `myflag=` argument.

Comment: I'm not seeing why though. Setting `myflag` to `foo` yields the same so there's nothing special about `myflag`.

Comment: "setting `myflat` to `foo` yields the same" what does that mean exactly? Look, you haven't even provided the full error message. I'm not really sure what you are expecting us to do.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'm not understanding why the parent class method wouldn't accept the `myflag` argument? doesn't `kwargs` mean that it accepts a variable number of keyward arguments? I thought you meant that the parent class doesn't accept `myflag` because there's something special about it, hence my response.

Comment: @digitalnomd You should edit your question and put there full traceback - to see exactly from where the error originates.

Comment: @AndrejKesely added the full traceback

Comment: The value does not matter.  Using `**kwargs` in a method signature lets you accept any keyword arguments *in the function/method where that is in the signature*, but if you pass those kwargs to another function/method/class that does not accept one of the keywords, then it will cause a TypeError.  The fact that `**kwargs` was used to pass them to that function does not matter - the actual signature of what you are calling is what matters.

Comment: @dskrypa the parent class signature accepts `**kwargs` which is why I'm confused why it's not accepting an arbitrary number of keyword args including `myflag`. Thanks.

Comment: The method that *it* is calling with those kwargs does not accept a `myflag` argument.